# .NET Core CLI Only Works For One User

Tags: 14.04, aws

I have spun up an AWS EC2 instance using the latest AMI from the Jenkins website. I then installed .net core via the tarball from the Microsoft website. (for reasons I won't get in to, adding the extra package source to use `apt-get` is not an option)

I unpacked the tarball to `/usr/bin/dotnetcore`, and then added this to the path `env` variable. The CLI works fine from this user, but if I `su` over to the tomcat user (which is what jenkins runs as), all dotnet CLI commands fail with the following error message:

```
Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005
```

I took a look at the file permissions for the CLI files and they all appeared to be fine.

How do I get the CLI to work for all the users on this box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this doing the following:

1. Run `strace dotnet run`
2. find the following line in the output `mknod("/tmp/clr-debug-pipe-8216-6278628-in", S_IFIFO|0700) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`
3. Give all users the same permissions on the /tmp folder that the owner has